# Nearest unblockaded core province with a port. How is this computed?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

How does the game compute the nearest unblockaded core province with a port? I am playing as Ming and have cored and colonized Midway islands (picture below). However, the game still says my closest unblockaded core is in Gubbi Gubbi (Australia). How is this computed and why is Midway Islands not my closest port?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a) a core and b) a [dock](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Dock#Normal_and_Special) (or any better port). Since you cored it, you probably forgot to construct a port in Midway.

The calculation is the same as the distance measurement used for sea attrition. I am not certain if it is affected by trade winds, that could be another reason.

(In older versions you could also rent port access from another country, iirc, but that was removed around 1.5-ish.)

Comment: I don't think that is true. There is no building called "port", all coastal provinces has one.

Comment: @Nix I've added a link and fixed the wording.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you don't need the building. Port refers to a coastal province - a province that shits can dock into.

Comment: @Sunspawn I think an actual dock is required, I had the exact problem as OP myself (not sure if same island tho) and building a dock seemed to fix it, I recall. Maybe OP could comment if this answer fixed his problem, too (it was accepted, so I guess it did).

I don't have EU4 installed right now, I'll try to test it later. Of course if you tested it, let me know. Or is there is another aspect to this that we missed?